# Integration help - question: $e^{-\sin(x)}$

Tags: integration

I would really like some help with the integration of $e^{-\sin(x)}$. Thanks to anyone who will help :)

Given that $\sin(x) > \frac{2x}{\pi}$ for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, where $$\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\sin x}\,dx<\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-2x/\pi}\,dx$$

RTS:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\sin x}\,dx=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}e^{-\sin x}\,dx$$

Comment: i think that its cannot be made in terms of elementary functions

Comment: what do you exactly mean by this?

Comment: i mean that probably that the primitive cannot be given in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Do you mean that we are integrating over the interval $[0, \pi/2]$?

Comment: yes we are integrating over these borders

Comment: This doesn't have a nice closed-form solution.

Comment: See here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+exp%28-sin%28x%29%29+from+x%3D0..pi%2F2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-\sin x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$$
and since:
$$e^{-t}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k t^k}{k!},\qquad \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^k}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^k\theta\,d\theta=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)}$$
$($see [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) for more information$)$, it follows that:
$$ I = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)\Gamma(k+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\left(I_0(1)-L_0(1)\right)},$$
where $I_0$ and $L_0$ are a [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and a [Struve function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

---

As to why the integrand does not possess an anti-derivative expressible in terms of elementary functions, see [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: even though this is a great solution, we have not learnt this approach in our lessons

Comment: @Lucian: thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}}
^{\ds{\dsc{\sin\pars{x}}=\dsc{t}\ \imp\ \dsc{x}=\dsc{\arcsin\pars{t}}}}\ =\
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\expo{-t}}{\root{1 - t^{2}}}\,\dd t
=\color{#66f}{\large -\,\frac{\pi}{2}\,{\rm M}_{0}\pars{1}}
\approx{\tt 0.8731}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$\ds{\,{\rm M}_{\nu}\pars{z}}$ is a
[Modified Struve Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.2#E6).

The result
$\ds{\pars{~\mbox{given in expression}\ \pars{1}~}}$ corresponds to $11.5.4$ in
[this link](http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.5.E4).